# http-server node strange character in console when start

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

I have installed http-server on windows computer like this:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

When I start the server in a directory where there is a HTML file with a very simple code of hello Word in the console of PowerShell I'm getting this :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This charecters are printing forever and the server is not serving the page.

Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70656184/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70597019/3001761

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `http-server` uses the `colors` package. They are switching to `chalk`: https://github.com/http-party/http-server/pull/785

More on this here: https://snyk.io/blog/open-source-npm-packages-colors-faker/

Comment: well, looks like it is lol They merged that PR.