# node.js getting module_not_found faker

Tags: node.js, faker, modulenotfounderror

I  am new to Node.js. I want to create mysql connection and insert data into the database and access it later. I installed, node.js, then using npm installed 'mysql' and 'faker'.
Using node.js I successfully connected to mysql, created database and tables(code in mysql1.js in the folder NODE-JS).

Then I went ahead to create fake data (code in fake_data.js) to insert into the table.
[screenshot of vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwIl8.jpg)

var faker = require("faker");

let first_name = faker.name.firstName();
let last_name = faker.name.lastName();

console.log(`Employee: ${prefix} ${first_name} ${last_name} ${suffix}`);

But this time I got error

```
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'D:\\DATABASES\\NODE-JS\\node_modules\\faker\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'faker'
```

package.json file contains the following dependencies

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "name": "node-js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

I tried,

```
var faker = require("./faker");
```

even then it throws error

please help me to rectify the problem. thanks

Comment: Aside from what Ahmed said, requiring packages with ./ means it's a local package, i.e. is file you wrote. Requiring node modules doesn't have the ./ In the path.

Comment: Will sure keep in mind Phix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happened with faker.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597019/what-happened-with-faker-js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The owner of faker deleted it from GitHub at v6.6.6
You can see that here:
https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/

So it is up to the community to complete it
The new repository:
https://github.com/faker-js/faker

> This is the official, stable fork of Faker.

### Installation

Please replace your `faker` dependency with `@faker-js/faker`.

```sh
npm install @faker-js/faker --save-dev
```

### Node.js

```js
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
```

Comment: Thank you buddy

Comment: @DheeranDP you're welcome, you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
npm install @faker-js/faker
```

and then, install in node.js the require:

```js
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
```