# Bower unable to install Faker@3.1.0

Tags: bower, faker, bower-install

We have an old ember app has `bower.json` with below configuration:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "Faker": "~3.1.0"
  }
}
```

It has been working for years, recently we found the below error in building

```
bower install
bower Faker#~3.1.0          not-cached https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js.git#~3.1.0
bower Faker#~3.1.0             resolve https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js.git#~3.1.0
bower Faker#~3.1.0        ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy ~3.1.0

Additional error details:
No versions found in https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js.git
```

I checked https://github.com/Marak/Faker.js, the error is right. There is no `3.1.0` anymore, the current version is `6.6.6`. But the git commit history cannot find `3.1.0` version anymore.

Is there a way for me to find the 3.1.0 back from somewhere? It seems the author clears the old versions?

Comment: The author deleted all of the [tags](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tags). This is not normal: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70597019/3001761.

Comment: Thank you very much, @jonrsharpe  Yes, I know the story now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [What happened with faker.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70597019/3001761), the library's original maintainer erased the whole history of the repository. Older versions of Faker are still available via `npm install`; resolving them from the NPM registry is stable, as they [prevent popular packages being unpublished](https://docs.npmjs.com/unpublishing-packages-from-the-registry) since [the `left-pad` debacle](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/). However the *tags* [no longer exist](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/tags) in the GitHub repository, hence Bower cannot find the package.

There is a [community-maintained fork](https://github.com/faker-js/faker) of faker.js that you could switch to, even though new Bower packages cannot be created. Per [the Bower documentation](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/):

> As Bower is deprecated, registering new Bower packages is not
> supported anymore. Neverthless you can install any GitHub repository
> as Bower package by putting full name in `bower.json`:
>
> ```
> {
>   "dependencies": {
>     "angular-cli": "angular/angular-cli#^9.1.3"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You can install any dependency from github with CLI as well:
>
> ```
> bower install angular/angular-cli --save
> ```

In your case, therefore, you should be able to resolve the issue as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "Faker": "faker-js/faker#~3.1.0"
  }
}
```